# Царское Село - а почему вдруг "село" с заглавной буквы?

Tags: орфография

Набираем в Гугле и Яндексе "царское село" - почти все ссылки используют написание "Царское Село". Второе слово с заглавной буквы.

Это подозрительно. У меня ощущение, что это писали люди, ориентирующиеся на правила английского языка.

Есть какой-то авторитетный источник на этот счёт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> § 169.  В географических и административно-территориальных названиях — названиях материков, морей, озер, рек, возвышенностей, гор, стран, краев, областей, населенных пунктов, улиц и т.п. — с прописной буквы пишутся все слова, кроме родовых понятий (остров, море, гора, область, провинция, улица, площадь и т.п.), служебных слов, а также слов года, лет.
>
> Примечание 1. Нарицательные существительные в составных географических названиях пишутся с прописной буквы, если они употреблены не в своем обычном значении, напр.: *Новая Земля*, *Огненная Земля* (архипелаги), *Золотой Рог* (бухта), *Чешский Лес* (горы), *Белая Церковь*, *Минеральные Воды*, *Сосновый Бор*, *Вятские Поляны*, ***Царское  Село*** **(города)**, *Пушкинские Гэры* [sic], *Камское Устье* (поселки), *Голодная Губа* (озеро), *Большой  Бассейн* (плоскогорье), *Золотые Ворота* (пролив), *Кузнецкий Мост*, *Охотный Ряд*, *Земляной Вал* (улицы), *Никитские Ворота*, *Рогожская Застава* (площади), *Марьина Роща* (район в Москве), *Елисейские Поля* (улица в Париже).

Царское Село является не селом, а городом. Поэтому "Село" не используется как родовое понятие в этом названии. Поэтому оба слова—с заглавной буквы.

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.

Comment: Пушкинские Гэры? Это что и где?

Answer (score 1):

Слово "Село" входит в топоним, это не родовое слово. Отсюда и заглавная.
Проверяется очень легко. Вы нигде не найдете упоминания о селе "Царском". Только о "Царском Селе".

Что же касается отсылки к ПО-56, то по современным представлениям формулировка "не в своем обычном значении" нуждается в некотором пояснении. Дело не в том, что Царское Село - город, просто "Село" - неотъемлемая часть **названия**.

Есть в Московской области деревня Новая Деревня. И Деревня в названии тут все одно с заглавной.    Потому, что это не "деревня Новая", это именно "деревня Новая Деревня".

Comment: Вот как раз вся эта тема с "неотъемлемой частью названия", применительно к русскому языку, меня немного смущает. Или, точней сказать, не до конца ясна. Поэтому я вопрос и задал :) Вот, к примеру, _Справочник издателя и автора_ (Мильчин, Чельцова; думаю, все эту книгу знают). Мы используем лишь одну заглавную букву, в самом начале. В английском это было бы _The Publisher's and Author's Handbook_, но не в русском.